# Re-purposing an existing GUI, while keeping most of the same functionality

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

I'm developing a user management system, in which I would like to re-use the GUI for the Add User form for the Edit User form, which just changing a few functions.

For example, in my Add Users, the User ID is set to the next available ID, and the Username, password, confirm password, and group are left blank. There is an Add User button that performs validation on the above mentioned fields, and the title of the form is "Add User"

All that needs to change for Edit user is to fill in the data from the user being edited (Getting the DataRow from my DataGridView is not a problem) and changing the Add button to an "Edit User" button while still performing the same validation, and changing the title of the form to "Edit User".

Is such a thing possible? What would this type of use be called so I could google it more efficiently?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without helping me out. Much appreciated.

Comment: Question shows no effort on your side. Have you even tried something? Downvoted and voted to close.

Comment: I was trying to check on event sender and seeing which button launched the form, but this proved difficult, and would require lots of rewriting of code. I've tried googling "GUI reuse" and "GUI repuporsing" to at least see what sort of help is out there, or to find better terms, since I'm sure I'm not calling it the right thing.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I can accomplish what I want by having separate contructor calls.

Comment: Man, tough crowd. I disagree with this being closed. I think it was an honest question that has an answer to it (below).

Comment: I agree with Bob, you should go on with seperate constructor calls. Maybe pass an `enum` value to show what you want to do (Edit, Add, ...).

Comment: REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE-OPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPEEEEEEEEEEEEENNNNNNNN!

Comment: @Carl et al., please read the FAQ as to what kinds of questions are appropriate for SO. For example, merely being "honest" and "has an answer" are not sufficient. If you disagree with this it is pointless to whine about it in comments; take it to Meta, there is a link at the top of the page. Also note that closed questions are not deleted and can be reopened easily if the questioner adds more information. Since there is an accepted answer there is little point in reopening it.

Comment: Yey! I got mentioned :) :) Seriously though, imo, the question is a valid one and it can be "reasonably answered in its current form". As you say there is no point re-opening as it has an answer, however, there was no point closing it either as it has an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, and it's done all the time. When you instantiate your form for add, you'll typically do something like this:

```
using (AddUserForm form = new AddUserForm())
{
  form.ShowDialog();
}
```

And if you want to edit a user:

```
using (AddUserForm form = new AddUserForm(user))
{
  form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Notice that you'll have two constructors for the form. Within the code for the AddUserForm (which you should really call ModifyUserForm, or UserForm), you'll do an Add() if the user is null, and an Update() if it's not null.

Example constructors:

```
public AddUserForm()
{
  this._user = new User();
}

public AddUserForm(User user)
{
  this._user = user;
}
```

Then save:

```
private void SaveUser()
{
  if (this._userId == 0)
  {
    MyDal.AddUser(this._user);
    return;
  }

  MyDal.UpdateUser(this._user);
}
```

I did this all without Visual Studio, so I don't promise it compiles. :)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but not as elegantly as you have it here. I'll alter my code a bit, but I appreciate you taking the time to actually help me out. :)

Comment: Glad to help. Don't let the downvotes bother you. That happens sometimes. Good question, bro.